My ant build fails concerning to node and npm - "npm error for site : Permission denied (publickey)."
Please find my ant target details concerning to node and npm for which my build process fails.
<!-- Task to Install the required node modules -->
<target name="resolve-npm" depends="-detect-resolve-npm-required, require-node" unless="node_modules.uptodate">
    <echo>Installing the node modules specified in package.json</echo>
    <exec dir="." executable="${npm}" logError="yes" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="install" if: set="isDev"/>
        <arg value="clean-install" unless:set="isDev"/>
    </exec>
    <touch file="node_modules/node_modules.uptodate"/>
    <property name="node_modules.uptodate" value="true"/>
</target>

Here is the error what I was getting for my ant build process
 [exec] resolve-npm:
 [exec]      [echo] Installing the node modules specified in package.json
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1: ≡ƒÖî  Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated nomnom@1.5.2: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated formidable@1.2.2: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: https:// bit.ly /2ZEqIau
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.12.1: ≡ƒÜ¿ This package has been deprecated in favor of separate inclusion of a polyfill and regenerator-runtime (when needed). See the @babel/polyfill docs (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) for more information.
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated superagent@3.8.3: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at <https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases>.
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn deprecated core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup   [
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup     'C:\\ucd-mono-repo\\server\\node_modules\\dojo',
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\ucd-mono-repo\server\node_modules\dojo\testsDOH\_base\loader\i18n-exhaustive\built-i18n-test\152-build-with-layers-and-preloads\nls\ab'] {
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\ucd-mono-repo\\server\\node_modules\\dojo\\testsDOH\\_base\\loader\\i18n-exhaustive\\built-i18n-test\\152-build-with-layers-and-preloads\\nls\\ab'
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup     }
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup   ],
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup   [
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup     'C:\\ucd-mono-repo\\server\\node_modules\\dojo',
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\ucd-mono-repo\server\node_modules\dojo\testsDOH\_base\loader\i18n-exhaustive\built-i18n-test\152-build\nls'] {
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup       errno: -4048,
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\ucd-mono-repo\\server\\node_modules\\dojo\\testsDOH\\_base\\loader\\i18n-exhaustive\\built-i18n-test\\152-build\\nls'
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup     }
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup   ]
 [exec]      [exec] npm warn cleanup ]
 [exec]      [exec] npm error code 128
 [exec]      [exec] npm error An unknown git error occurred
 [exec]      [exec] npm error command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote git@mygithub-site.com:urbancode/launch-api-spec-converter.git
 [exec]      [exec] npm error git@mygithub-site.com: Permission denied (publickey).
 [exec]      [exec] npm error fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 [exec]      [exec] npm error
 [exec]      [exec] npm error Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 [exec]      [exec] npm error and the repository exists.
 [exec]      [exec]
 [exec]      [exec] npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\anand.sathasivam\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-30T08_53_00_954Z-debug-0.log
 [exec]
 [exec] BUILD FAILED
 [exec] C:\ucd-mono-repo\server\build.xml:2400: exec returned: 128
 [exec]
 [exec] Total time: 2 minutes 41 seconds
 BUILD FAILED
 C:\ucd-mono-repo\build.xml:26: exec returned: 1

I do have node installed in my system. Here are the details.
I did this command execution once to upgrade npm and node
npm install -g npm

Please find node and npm version
> node -v
v21.2.0

> npm -version
10.6.0

I have found the error what I supposed to looking into
 [exec]      [exec] npm error command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote git@mygithub-site.com:urbancode/launch-api-spec-converter.git
 [exec]      [exec] npm error git@mygithub-site.com: Permission denied (publickey).

But, not sure why am I getting this, because I have done the necessary changes updating public key on GitHub site settings page.
Please advise on what I have to do

I run into a similar problem with my project after running the npm@10.6.0 upgrade. Took me few hours. When I rerun that command with npm@10.5.0 all errors are gone. And I can build my app.
Not a solution, but I checked all dependencies, rebuild, upgraded, downgraded whatever they wanted. Nothing worked for me, until I rolled back the NPM update.
Waiting for a new update to try again.

looks more like a comment than an answer
